# IBM Collaboration QuickStart image v3.5 - Softlayer - After logging in everything is access denied

Tags: ibm-sbt

I have a Softlayer instance with IBM Collaboration QuickStart image v3.5 installed. Following the guide [here](http://ibmdw.net/social/2014/02/04/ibm-collaboration-quickstart-image-now-softlayer), I have the server up and running. However whenever I log in using the details I provided during the setup wizard, I immediately get an 'access denied' message.

- I have tried logging in as admin with no success.
- I have tried finding the logs (with no success) in order to see what is actually causing the problem.

I am not sure whether I have configured something wrong during the setup, any suggestions?

Comment: what admin are you logging in as? and what URL? - also an image would help

Comment: I was logging in as qsiadmin at /homepage/login/. That was saying the credentials were wrong. I also tried logging in as lsuarez which is when I was getting access denied.

Image: http://imgur.com/1xKpIkf

Comment: try /profiles and then see what it says, if it comes back with an error, logging in, I'll ask for more details, if it does not, you'll have to run a command to import the SSL Certificate into the truststore.

Comment: There was no error, it still does not show me as being logged in though. But that seems like progress! What command do I need to run? Thank you for your help!

Comment: run this command /local/qsi/was/util/updateTrustStores.sh it should make the homepage useable... if not, update the thread here, and I'll walk you through the manual steps

Answer (score 0):

in this case, the best result is to rerun the sync_all_dns.sh command. 
The command enables the users in the Directory to be populated.

Then the user's should be able to login successfully.